# Check docker-swarm status from a node that is not a part of swarm

Tags: docker, health-check, swarm

I have swarm cluster and want to perform health checks on it from a separate node which is on same private network. If I were doing this from the cluster itself, I would simply execute `docker node ls`
and check if any of my nodes were "Unavailable".

So, does docker-swarm have any endpoints from which I could get the same or similar data as the output of `docker node ls` command?

I just need a way to reach my managers from the node that is not a part of swarm.
Any idea is much appreciated!